# What is the difference between these two ways to create an element?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = document.createElement('div');

a.id = "myDiv";
```

and

```
var a = document.createElement('div').id = "myDiv";
```

What is the difference between them such that the first one works and the second one doesn't?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting the `id` of the element does not *return* the element. It returns `"myDiv"` actually, so the var `a` is getting set to `"myDiv"` instead of the div itself.

Comment: But `.createElement();` returns an element so why shouldn't I be able to manipulate it from there?

Comment: @David: Because you already have. You've referred to its `.id` property. So `var a = document.createElement('div').id = "myDiv";` creates an element, sets its `id`, return the string `"myDiv"` for storage in the `a` variable, and immediately makes that element available for garbage collection because nothing has an outstanding reference ot it. Since you don't have a reference to it, you can't do anything else to it, or use it for anything.

Answer (score 2):

The second one doesn't work because the "return" value from createElement is used to set the id. As that's an assignment and not chaining, it doesn't return the reference to the new element back to "a" and thus fails.

Answer (score 0):

The second doesn't work as you're creating an element but immediately performing an operation upon it. The `a` variable is set to the string "myDiv" instead.

Answer (score 0):

`foo = 'bar'` as a statement actually returns a value, which is `'bar'`.

```
a = document.createElement('div'); //this sets `a` to DOM Node

a = document.createElement('div').id = 'myDiv'; //this sets `a` to 'myDiv'
//it's the same as
document.createElement('div').id = 'myDiv';
a = 'myDiv';
```

---

## Don't ever do this

If you wanted to set both the ID and the `a` variable in one line, you could use parens:

```
(a = document.createElement('div')).id = 'myDiv';
```

That's because `a = document.createElement('div')` retuns the newly created DOM Node.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a short way, you can write :

```
(window.a=document.createElement('div')).id="myDiv";
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/F23cD/

Comment: But then `a` is a global variable, and the code is much less readable. I would suggest just having the statement on two lines; more correct and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In the first statement you put the created element of type "div" into variable "a", and then set the element property "id" of "a" to "myDiv". Then "a" is now the element.

In the second statement you:

1. create the element of type "div": document.createElement('div')
2. set the element property "id" to "myDiv" and
3. set "a" to "myDiv" also

Then, "a" is now "myDiv" and not the element.

Answer (score 0):

//  use this

a.setAttribute("id","myDiv");